# SQL - Searching for a string in database minus a section of it

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, url

I'm searching a database for those that have accessed certain websites, but want to remove part of the url as the numbers within it are not static.

For instance if this "http://m.mlb.com/news/article/215311692/red-sox-send-off-equipment-on-truck-day/" was the url I want to remove the "215311692" so that i get all mlb.com results with that specific title.

Typically I use this code "ilike '%'||SUBSTRING(page_url, E'(([a-z0-9-]+\.){1,2}[a-z]{2,4})')||'%'" on the join. What do I need to add or change in order to remove the numbers in the the url in my search?

Comment: did you try `regexp_replace(url,'/\d+','')`?

Comment: Can you show more than just a single example? It's not clear if you always access  "http://m.mlb.com/news/article/" or if others are different.